# How to run the code in the server its command is used

Tags: discord.js

So, I have made this code

```
const { Guild } = require("discord.js");


Guild.roles.create({
    name: 'Kırmızı', 
    color: '#ff0000', 
    reason: 'Before giving color roles, you need to add the roles to server'
})
```

I know that I should be writing the guild name but I want it to run this code in the server its command is used. How can I do that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close. You get the guild from the message:

```
message.guild.roles.create({
    name: 'Super Cool Blue People',
    color: 'BLUE',
    reason: 'we needed a role for Super Cool People',
});
```

It does depend on how you are triggering this interaction, e.g. message, interaction, reaction, etc.

If you are doing it from a reaction, for example:

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
        reaction.message.guild.roles.create({
            name: 'Super Cool Red People',
            color: 'RED',
            reason: 'we needed a role for Super Cool People',
        });
    }
});
```

[Roles](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=create)
[Reactions](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#reacting-to-messages)